# What's wrong in this batch/command script?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
echo please enter the correct code in order to continue
set /p %password%=
if %password%==Puzzle (
cls
echo Loading...
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
cls
echo Your next step is "zhekw://vftqi.yczbpw.qzh/jazp/y/"
pause
exit
) else (
echo Loading...
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
echo You have Entered the wrong password, access declined
pause
)
```

I am new to batch, so I don't really understand what is wrong with this

Comment: To **set** a variable don't enlose it in `%` signs. This would reference another variable name stored in password, which isn't initialized in your batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your issue was provided in the comments by LotPings, the syntax is `Set /P "VariableName=PromptMessage"` not `Set /P "%Variable%=PromptMessage"`.

Here's a modified example of your script:

```bat
@Echo Off 
Set /P "password=Please enter the correct code in order to continue: "
ClS
Echo Loading...
Timeout 5 /NoBreak > Nul
ClS
If Not "%password%"=="Puzzle" (
    Echo You have Entered the wrong password, access declined
    GoTo :EndIt
)
Echo Your next step is "zhekw://vftqi.yczbpw.qzh/jazp/y/"
Rem rest of code here


:EndIt
Pause
Exit /B
```

*If case sensitivity for the password input isn't important, change line `7` to `If /I Not…`*

Answer (score 1):

You set a variable as:

```
Set /p "password=enter a password.: "
```

Then only once it is set you call it with the percentage signs:

```
%password%
```

Also always enclose `if` statement variables in double quotes, to eliminate possible whitepace.

```
if "%password%"=="Puzzle"
```

And you could probably replace ping with timeout, depending on your windows version.

```
Timeout /t 5
```